# Is this SAR-related question on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I wonder where is the best place to ask this question. It is about SAR systems that is used in remote sensing but involves signal processing.

The only reason that makes me dubious about asking this question in here is that maybe signal processing experts are not familiar at all with the structure of SLC, GRD or MLC files.
Where can I get the most comprehensive answer? here or in [GIS](http://gis.stackexchange.com)?

[What does it mean to store cross products in SAR product data file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160729/what-does-it-mean-to-store-cross-products-in-sar-product-data-file)

Answer (score 1):

The question seems more about GIS and/or file formats than signal processing.  I'd suggest leaving the question on GIS for a bit longer and see who responds.